# I'm trying to write code to calculate the power needed for a process that becomes more efficient the more divisions it has.

Tags: python

I think this should work, but my IDE always fails to run after a long 
   delay, citing memory issues.
    The key thing I want from this code is to be able to get the total energy needed based 
    upon how wide the gap between each slice that brings 1.2 to 5 is. 
     ff(a, b) is the only place to look for issues, the rest works as intended,
    or at least is good enough

```
ip = 1.2
fp = 5
#The process is more efficient the smaller b -a is hence the following function
def efficiency(a, b):
    eff = a/b
    return eff
#The energy difference between input and output is directly related to b-a
def power(a,b):
    pwr = b-a
    return pwr
#This gives the actual energy needed for a change from a to b
def workneeded(a, b):
    wrk = ((efficiency(a, b))**(-1)) * power(a, b)
    return wrk
def ff(a, b):
#I had trouble with other options so I decided to simply start with any empty list
    lis = [0,0]
#This is what I think is a way to make the function work until a reaches b through += it
#it stands for iteration
    while b != a:
        it = .38
        a += it
        tot = workneeded(a-it, a)
        lis.append(tot)
#I think this makes the function finish by the point that a = b
    if a == b:
#What I'm really after is the next line
        print(sum(lis))
ff(ip, fp)
```

Comment: add this in the while loop print(b,a) to check the value of b and a. After running your program I see that value of b is fixed to 5 but value of a is increasing from 1.2 to infinity. That's why the while loop gets stuck as b never equal to a. Check the condition of while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `while a != b:`, try to use `while a - b > tol`, `tol` being a very small number.

Answer (score 0):

In `ff(a, b)`, your `b` will never be equal to `a`, and the loop never ends.

But why?

That's because all numbers are stored as binary in the memory.

If you do some calculating to get the binary of a decimal, it will become a repeating decimal in most cases.

It's impossible to store all the digits, so the number is now slightly different from your intention.

Try this in IDLE:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> bin(ctypes.c_int.from_buffer(ctypes.c_float(0.38)).value)
>>> bin(5)
```

Replace the floating number as you like. You will find that 3.8+1.2 is not equal to 5.